# When an instance is created in java program?

Tags: java, singleton, instance

I'd like to write singleton class for java.
I found a sample program, as follows.

```
public class Singleton {
  private static Singleton singleton = new Singleton();

  private Singleton() {
    System.out.println("instance is created.");
  }

  public static Singleton getInstance() {
    return singleton;
  }
}
```

You know, constructor is private method, not called.

How can I make a singleton instance?

When an instance is created in java program?

thank you.

Comment: `Singleton singleton = Singleton.getInstance();` ?

Comment: What is the problem. It looks ok.

Comment: The program is running.The problem is I didnt know a timing to make instance.thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singleton instance will be created the first time you'll call Singleton.getInstance(). The class will be loaded, and the singleton variable initialized, and returned by the getInstance() method.

Comment: The method doesn't even have to be called, loading the class should suffice. Accessing the object is another story.

Comment: You're right, but unless using reflection, the class won't be loaded without calling getInstance or any other static method it could expose.

Comment: @X.L.Ant `Class<?> c = Singleton.class;` will load the class.

Comment: Thanks a lot.So, I can make an instance without calling constructor.

Comment: @assylias: Your stanza will load the class but not initialize it. Therefore there will be no instance of `Singleton`. Try it!

Answer (score 3):

As Joshua Bloch says in his [Effective Java 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) book, starting from Java 5 the best way to implement a singleton is to use enum:

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
    // all the necessary methods go here
}
```

This pattern for singleton implementation helps to avoid certain serialization/deserialization issues. See Item 3 of Effective Java 2nd Edition for more details.